# Print the stack trace of an exception

Tags: java, exception

How do I print the stack trace of an exception to a stream other than stderr? One way I found is to use getStackTrace() and print the entire list to the stream.

Comment: If you want to get exception trace as String you can call `getStackTrace` method of Trowable (the Exception) that will return array of `StackTraceElement` objects that you can combine to one String (using toString method of that object to get one line of a trace).

Answer (score 68, accepted):

`Throwable.printStackTrace(..)` can take a `PrintWriter` or `PrintStream` argument:

```
} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace(new java.io.PrintStream(yourOutputStream));
}
```

That said, consider using a logger interface like [SLF4J](http://www.slf4j.org/) with an logging implementation like [LOGBack](http://logback.qos.ch/) or [log4j](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html).

Comment: how would we print this with log4j? log.error(ex.printStackTrace())?

Answer (score 91):

There is an alternate form of Throwable.printStackTrace() that takes a print stream as an argument. http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#printStackTrace(java.io.PrintStream)

E.g.

```
catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace(System.out);
}
```

This will print the stack trace to std out instead of std error.

Comment: @FranklinYu, the whole point of the question is that he doesn't want to print to stderr, but to another arbitrary stream.

Comment: instead of `System.out` you can use `e.printStackTrace(new PrintStream("path.txt"))`

Answer (score 88):

Not beautiful, but a solution nonetheless:

```
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter( writer );
exception.printStackTrace( printWriter );
printWriter.flush();

String stackTrace = writer.toString();
```

Comment: This is what i needed (even though I feel really dirty using it!)

Answer (score 13):

For the android dev minimalists: `Log.getStackTraceString(exception)`

Comment: You can't use this to print to an arbitrary stream. It is useful only if you have a logger configured.

Comment: I liked this minimalist approach but it didn't jell with my slf4j :(

Answer (score 13):

Apache commons provides utility to convert the stack trace from throwable to string.

Usage:

```
ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(e)
```

For complete documentation refer to
https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/index.html

Comment: While this answer looks very much correct, it is not an answer to the question. OP asked how he could print the stack trace to another stream.

Comment: Even though this might not answer OP's question, I think this is the best way to have an exception as a String, using a very well established format. Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

I have created a method that helps with getting the stackTrace:

```
private static String getStackTrace(Exception ex) {
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(500);
    StackTraceElement[] st = ex.getStackTrace();
    sb.append(ex.getClass().getName() + ": " + ex.getMessage() + "\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < st.length; i++) {
      sb.append("\t at " + st[i].toString() + "\n");
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The [Throwable](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/%5C) class provides two methods named `printStackTrace`, one that accepts a `PrintWriter` and one that takes in a `PrintStream`, that outputs the stack trace to the given stream.  Consider using one of these.

Answer (score 3):

With slf4j e.g via `lombok`'s `@Slf4j` annotation

`log.error("error", e);`

Answer (score 1):

See [javadoc](http://download.java.net/jdk7/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#printStackTrace%28java.io.PrintStream%29)

```
out = some stream ...
try
{
}
catch ( Exception cause )
{
      cause . printStrackTrace ( new PrintStream ( out ) ) ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in a more compact stack trace with more information (package detail) that looks like:

```
  java.net.SocketTimeoutException:Receive timed out
    at j.n.PlainDatagramSocketImpl.receive0(Native Method)[na:1.8.0_151]
    at j.n.AbstractPlainDatagramSocketImpl.receive(AbstractPlainDatagramSocketImpl.java:143)[^]
    at j.n.DatagramSocket.receive(DatagramSocket.java:812)[^]
    at o.s.n.SntpClient.requestTime(SntpClient.java:213)[classes/]
    at o.s.n.SntpClient$1.call(^:145)[^]
    at ^.call(^:134)[^]
    at o.s.f.SyncRetryExecutor.call(SyncRetryExecutor.java:124)[^]
    at o.s.f.RetryPolicy.call(RetryPolicy.java:105)[^]
    at o.s.f.SyncRetryExecutor.call(SyncRetryExecutor.java:59)[^]
    at o.s.n.SntpClient.requestTimeHA(SntpClient.java:134)[^]
    at ^.requestTimeHA(^:122)[^]
    at o.s.n.SntpClientTest.test2h(SntpClientTest.java:89)[test-classes/]
    at s.r.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)[na:1.8.0_151]
```

you can try to use [Throwables.writeTo](https://github.com/zolyfarkas/spf4j/blob/master/spf4j-core/src/main/java/org/spf4j/base/Throwables.java#L536) from the [spf4j](http://www.spf4j.org) lib.