# Connection error while communicating to wiFly

Tags: java, android, sockets

I am trying to set up communication between my android device and [wiFly](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/9954)(RN-171) module. I create an ad-hoc network on the android device and connect the wiFly to the network. The wiFly is configured to listen on 169.254.1.1:2000. I create socket in the app to communicate with the wiFly. Code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
            .permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

        Socket echoSocket = null;
        PrintWriter out = null;
        BufferedReader in = null;

        try {
            echoSocket = new Socket("169.254.1.1", 2000);
            out = new PrintWriter(echoSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                                    echoSocket.getInputStream()));
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            System.err.println("Don't know about host: wiFly.");
            System.exit(1);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Couldn't get I/O for "
                           + "the connection to: wiFly.");
        }

    BufferedReader stdIn = new BufferedReader(
                               new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String userInput;
    while ((userInput = stdIn.readLine()) != null) {
        out.println(userInput);
        System.out.println("echo: " + in.readLine());
    }
        out.close();
    in.close();
    stdIn.close();
    echoSocket.close();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}
}
```

Sorry for using StrictMode. Will switch to AsyncTask once this runs.
Following is the warning message:

```
03-29 21:55:40.352: W/AdHoc(15118): failed to connect to /169.254.1.1 (port 2000): connect failed: ENETUNREACH (Network is unreachable)
03-29 21:55:40.352: W/System.err(15118): java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /169.254.1.1 (port 2000): connect failed: ENETUNREACH (Network is unreachable)
03-29 21:55:40.362: W/System.err(15118):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:114)
03-29 21:55:40.362: W/System.err(15118):    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
03-29 21:55:40.362: W/System.err(15118):    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
03-29 21:55:40.362: W/System.err(15118):    at java.net.Socket.startupSocket(Socket.java:566)
03-29 21:55:40.362: W/System.err(15118):    at java.net.Socket.tryAllAddresses(Socket.java:127)
03-29 21:55:40.362: W/System.err(15118):    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:177)
03-29 21:55:40.362: W/System.err(15118):    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:149)
03-29 21:55:40.362: W/System.err(15118):    at com.example.udp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:33)
03-29 21:55:40.362: W/System.err(15118):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4492)
03-29 21:55:40.362: W/System.err(15118):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
03-29 21:55:40.362: W/System.err(15118):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
03-29 21:55:40.362: W/System.err(15118):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
03-29 21:55:40.372: W/System.err(15118):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
03-29 21:55:40.372: W/System.err(15118):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
03-29 21:55:40.372: W/System.err(15118):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-29 21:55:40.372: W/System.err(15118):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-29 21:55:40.372: W/System.err(15118):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
03-29 21:55:40.372: W/System.err(15118):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-29 21:55:40.372: W/System.err(15118):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-29 21:55:40.382: W/System.err(15118):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
03-29 21:55:40.382: W/System.err(15118):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
03-29 21:55:40.382: W/System.err(15118):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-29 21:55:40.382: W/System.err(15118): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: connect failed: ENETUNREACH (Network is unreachable)
03-29 21:55:40.382: W/System.err(15118):    at libcore.io.Posix.connect(Native Method)
03-29 21:55:40.382: W/System.err(15118):    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:85)
03-29 21:55:40.382: W/System.err(15118):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:127)
03-29 21:55:40.382: W/System.err(15118):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
03-29 21:55:40.382: W/System.err(15118):    ... 21 more
03-29 21:55:40.392: W/System.err(15118): Couldn't get I/O for the connection to: wiFly.
```

I run it on android 4.0.4, and have included all the necessary permission needed in the Manifest file.

Comment: Could you post what the actual IOException e message is? it is possible that the exception happens on your PrintWriter or BufferedReader lines and that it actually is connecting.

Comment: @spartacus Its a warning, so there wont be any more details. Anyways, edited. :)

Comment: That appears to still be the error you are printing out.  What I want to see is the IOException error like this e.getMessage()

Comment: Also a stack trace as what led to that exception would be nice as well to see exactly what call it is failing on. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6822968/print-the-stack-trace-of-an-exception

Comment: Ok it is definitely failing on new Socket("169.254.1.1", 2000). Sorry but short of coming over there and checking your network settings I won't be able to answer your question.

Comment: It isn't a warning, it's the result of catching an exception, and there are more details, and instead of printing the exception message itself you have made up your own message, which is useless, and you've also put it into your title here, which is even more useless.

Comment: Looks like the emulator doesn't know that it's connected to a network. Try re-starting the emulator. Or try opening a URL with the browser app. If the browser works, try to open this URL on the browser itself, and see if it's able to connect to it.

Answer (score 0):

What IP address does your phone have?

You need to configure your phone to have an ip address in the same range as the wifly module or have the wifly give you an ip via its dhcp server.

If you haven't upgraded your firmware to v4 then you should probably do that first, it fixes some issues but has one distinct advantage over v2 firmware - it creates a soft AP that your device can connect to and will, by default, give your phone an ip address. You'll then be able to connect to it with few issues.

[Roving networks upgrade info](http://www.rovingnetworks.com/FAQs/How_do_I_upgrade_to_WiFly_v4_00_from_earlier_WiFly_versions)

As a side note running in soft ap mode the wifly gets an ip address of 1.2.3.4 - no idea why they chose that :/

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use 1.2.3.4 for any device. 1.2.3.4 is a real-world IP address, in Australia. Any engineer who creates a device with a default IP address of 1.2.3.4 is a moron. You cannot just pick a number at random for an IP address; that's not how it works.

My WiFly RN-171XV documentation tells me that, following upgrading to v4.40 firmware and a factory reset, the device placed in hardware AP mode has a default IP address of 1.2.3.4, but it does not respond at that address, and the DHCP server does not respond to any request.

Hence, I have totally lost contact with the device. It is not responding on Tx/Rx, either.

Under the old firmware, v2.30, the Ad Hoc mode default IP address was 169.254.1.1, which is a link-local address reserved for self-assignment in the absence of DHCP, which was not the case. You cannot use a link-local address as a default address in this circumstance.

The foregoing clearly indicates that the so-called engineer who wrote the firmware had no knowledge or understanding of the Internet Protocol. It seems like a great device, so far as the hardware goes, but the firmware was apparently written by the mentally retarded.

Comment: Did you find a solution?  I have the exact same problem.